# AJAX POST requests not being received by PHP via $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm building part of a Firefox OS app and I'm having to use the OpenBadges API, meaning I can't use more PHP, which would make this much simpler.

The problem I'm having now is that my data sent from an AJAX POST request:

```
$(function(){
   $("#submitBtn").click(function(){
      var mail = $('#mail').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'text',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'scripts/test.php',
        data: { 
            mail: mail 
        },
        success: function(data){
        var jdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert("success! X: " + data);
        }

      });
   });
});
```

...isn't being received by my PHP script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['mail']))
    {

        $id_url = 'http://backpack.openbadges.org/displayer/convert/email';
        $mail = $_POST['mail'];
        $email = 'email='.$mail;

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $id_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $email);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec ($curl);
        curl_close ($curl);

        $user_id = json_decode($result)->userId;
        $test_var = json_decode($result);
        echo $result;
        //echo $test_var;
        //echo $user_id;

    }

//echo $mail;

?>
```

I keep getting a "cancelled" status on my PHP script in the Chrome dev tools Network tab, and I can see that it's sending the input in the form of "example%40gmail.com" instead of "@", but I'm not sure if that's part of the problem or not.

I've been looking and tweaking my code for about two days trying to figure out the problem, but none of the fixes that have worked for other people have worked for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` return?

Comment: Look in the network tab of the developer tools. See if it's 404ing or 200ing. If it's 404ing, check your path. If it's 200ing, then we have an interesting problem.

Comment: @Samsquanch No http code, just "Cancelled".

Comment: @Mooseman "array(0){}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting "cancelled" because the link you're clicking is being executed at the same time as your ajax call, in turn canceling it. What you need to do is use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the click from canceling your request.

```
$(function(){
   $("#submitBtn").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // don't cancel the request
      var mail = $('#mail').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'text',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'scripts/test.php',
        data: { 
            mail: mail 
        },
        success: function(data){
        var jdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert("success! X: " + data);
        }

      });
   });
});
```

Comment: That fixed my cancelled problem! Thank you. Now it's giving me nothing back when I test the contents of $mail, though. It's showing a 200 OK, and undefined variable.

Comment: Are you checking `$mail` or `$_POST['mail']`?

Comment: $mail is $_POST['mail'] here, but I'm also trying echo var_dump($_POST) and coming up the same.
Actually I think $mail came up null and var_dump showed array(0){}.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['mail']);` before the if -- see what you get.

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: mail in /opt/lampp/htdocs/crisisvolunteer/scripts/test.php on line 2
NULL"

Comment: What does the ajax call look like in the network window? Is it sending through `mail`?

Comment: Yes, it's going through. "mail=example%40yahoo.com" That's what confuses me. I put example there instead of the email I'm actually using.

Comment: It's going to sound silly, but are you sure you haven't misspelled anything?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I haven't. No other ideas?

Comment: Changing my contentType to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" worked! Thanks for your help with the first problem!